# Trying to evaluate two classes with a BenchmarkDotNet test

Tags: c#, .net, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I'm trying to figure out which one of these classes below is faster, so I decided to write a BenchmarkDotNet test.

```cs
public class RequestSignerBenchmark
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void First()
    {
        var signer = RequestSigner2.FromSecret("hidden");

        var timestamp = TimestampProvider.Default.CurrentTimestamp();
        signer.Sign(timestamp, "GET", "products", "");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Second()
    {
        var signer = RequestSigner.FromSecret("hidden");

        var timestamp = TimestampProvider.Default.CurrentTimestamp();
        signer.Sign(timestamp, "GET", "products", "");
    }
}

// Program.cs
BenchmarkRunner.Run<RequestSignerBenchmark>();
```

I'm not sure that I'm running that the test I made is correct. Isn't the `First()` supposed to be faster judging by the code? If it's wrong, what would an appropriate test would look like?

```
| Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
|  First | 3.234 us | 0.0646 us | 0.1769 us |
| Second | 2.659 us | 0.0516 us | 0.0614 us |
```

### Classes to evaluate

```cs
public sealed class RequestSigner
{
    private readonly byte[] _base64Secret;

    public RequestSigner(byte[] base64Secret)
    {
        _base64Secret = base64Secret;
    }

    public static RequestSigner FromSecret(string secret)
    {
        return new RequestSigner(Convert.FromBase64String(secret));
    }

    public string Sign(string timestamp, string method, string requestPath, string body)
    {
        var orig = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timestamp + method.ToUpperInvariant() + requestPath + body);
        using var hmac = new HMACSHA256(_base64Secret);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(orig));
    }
}

public class RequestSigner2 : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HMACSHA256 _hmac;

    public RequestSigner2(byte[] base64Secret)
    {
        _hmac = new HMACSHA256(base64Secret);
    }

    public static RequestSigner2 FromSecret(string secret)
    {
        return new RequestSigner2(Convert.FromBase64String(secret));
    }

    public string Sign(string timestamp, string method, string requestPath, string body)
    {
        DoDisposeChecks();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(method) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestPath))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var orig = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timestamp + method.ToUpperInvariant() + requestPath + body);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(_hmac.ComputeHash(orig));
    }

    #region Disposable

    private bool _isDisposed;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Checks if this object has been disposed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">Thrown if the object has been disposed.</exception>
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    protected void DoDisposeChecks()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(RequestSigner2));
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Disposes of managed and unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">A value indicating whether or not to dispose of managed resources.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            _hmac.Dispose();
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you believe that the First (`RequestSigner2`) should be faster?

Comment: In addition, this is a big no no "Summary -> Benchmark was executed with attached debugger". You need to run in release _without_ the debugger attached, otherwise your results will most likely be skewed.

Comment: @DavidL, yes, I think so. And thanks, I was running it in Release, but with an attached debugger. However, the result are no different without the attached debugger. I edited the question with the results without the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, I believe your assertion that the `RequestSigner2` implementation should be faster "may" be incorrect based on how your test is currently structured.

You have two additional if checks in your `RequestSigner2` implementation that are having an impact on your performance (and we're talking about a nanosecond here...) if you do not reuse your `HMACSHA256` instance correctly, and currently you are not.

By removing both the checks, and wrapping your initialization of `RequestSigner2` in a using statement,

```
[Benchmark]
public void First()
{
    using var signer = RequestSigner2.FromSecret("aGlkZGVu");

    var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    signer.Sign(timestamp, "GET", "products", "");
}
```

I was able to achieve the following.

[image: benchmark]

Note that your "optimized" version actually allocates 8 more bytes.

I am guessing that your assumption was that reusing the `HMACSHA256` instance would be cheaper than initializing it each call. But interestingly enough, this is more expensive in your test.

I believe that you intend to reuse the signer in your actual application code, but this isn't mirrored in your benchmark code.

You should consider initializing the `RequestSigner2` once in a GlobalSetup step, then dispose it in a GlobalCleanup step.

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class RequestSignerBenchmark
{
    private RequestSigner2 _requestSigner2;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _requestSigner2 = RequestSigner2.FromSecret("aGlkZGVu");
    }

    [GlobalCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        _requestSigner2.Dispose();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void First()
    { 
        var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
        _requestSigner2.Sign(timestamp, "GET", "products", "");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Second()
    {
        var signer = RequestSigner.FromSecret("aGlkZGVu");

        var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
        signer.Sign(timestamp, "GET", "products", "");
    }
}
```

(Note that I've had to change a few parts of the benchmark implementation, due to not having your Timezone implementation).

*Now* we get the performance improvements you were expecting, even with both if checks added back in!

[image]